# Android Spinner border issue

Tags: android

I have make the spinner he work perfect but the design issue.
My Spinner code is

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="25dp">
    </Spinner>
```

Java code

```
spinnerShop = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.shop);
/*Shop Spinner*/
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> shopArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
        R.array.shopArray, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
shopArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerShop.setAdapter(shopArray);
```

@drawable/border code

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:radius="2dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/colorText" />
<stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

Border not shown arround the spinner
Show the image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a custom style on your style.xml file for your spinner. Then you will give this custom style to your spinner as below:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/product"
    style="@style/your_custom_spinner_style" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="25dp"/>
```

You will use your @drawable/border_code in your_custom_spinner_style in style.xml file as below:

```
<style name="your_custom_spinner_style">          
          <item name="android:background">@drawable/border_code</item>
          ........
     </style>
```

Please inform me after you try it.

Comment: In this way border shown but the spinner arrow not show.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawable="@drawable/border" // replace this line
    android:background="@drawable/border" // with this
    android:padding="25dp">
</Spinner>
```